# Monad for-comprehensions with implicit Monad fails, use inheritance?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I am running into this famous 10 year old ticket in Scala https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2823

Because I am expecting for-comprehensions to work like do-blocks in Haskell. And why shouldn't they, Monads go great with a side of sugar. At this point I have something like this:

```
import scalaz.{Monad, Traverse}
import scalaz.std.either._
import scalaz.std.list._

type ErrorM[A] = Either[String, A]
def toIntSafe(s : String) : ErrorM[Int] = {
   try {
      Right(s.toInt)
   } catch {
      case e: Exception => Left(e.getMessage)
   }
}

def convert(args: List[String])(implicit m: Monad[ErrorM], tr: Traverse[List]): ErrorM[List[Int]] = {
   val expanded = for {
      arg <- args
      result <- toIntSafe(arg)
   } yield result

   tr.sequence(expanded)(m)
}

println(convert(List("1", "2", "3")))
println(convert(List("1", "foo")))
```

And I'm getting the error

> "Value map is not a member of ErrorM[Int]" 
>   result <- toIntSafe(arg)

How do I get back to beautiful, monadic-comprehensions that I am used to? Some research shows the `FilterMonadic[A, Repr]` abstract class is what to extend if you want to be a comprehension, any examples of combining `FilterMonadic` with scalaz?

1. Can I reuse my Monad implicit and not have to redefine map, flatMap etc?
2. Can I keep my type alias and not have to wrap around Either or worse, redefine case classes for ErrorM?

Using Scala 2.11.8

EDIT: I am adding Haskell code to show this does indeed work in GHC without explicit Monad transformers, only traversals and default monad instances for Either and List.

```
type ErrorM = Either String

toIntSafe :: Read a => String -> ErrorM a
toIntSafe s = case reads s of
                  [(val, "")] -> Right val
                  _           -> Left $ "Cannot convert to int " ++ s

convert :: [String] -> ErrorM [Int]
convert = sequence . conv
    where conv s = do
            arg <- s
            return . toIntSafe $ arg

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn . show . convert $ ["1", "2", "3"]
    putStrLn . show . convert $ ["1", "foo"]
```

Comment: What Scala version are you using? Which library is `Monad` coming from? What are your imports? At a glance this is probably the fact that `Either` isn't right-biased prior to 2.12 but you haven't given us enough information to tell.

Comment: Scalaz or not... Wouldn't something like `args traverse toIntSafe` produce essentially the same result, only faster? Also, why are you passing `Monad[ErrorM]` and `Traverse[List]` from the outside. Do you expect to use this method for some other `Monad` and `Traverse` implementations that aren't the constants from the library?

Comment: Added version. @AndreyTyukin Correct, but this is not my real-use case. This is an example to ask "how do I for-comprehension" for monads.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, when you have a for comprehension, should the type of expressions to the right of `<-` be of the same monad, that is both `List[A]` (for possibly different As) or both `ErrorM[A]`, but not mixed?

Comment: My understanding is that ErrorM[List[A]] is also a Monad

Comment: Maybe, but `args: List[String]` and `toIntSafe(arg): ErrorM[Int]`, and the for comprehension above translates into `args.flatMap( (arg:String) => toIntSafe(arg).map( (result:Int) => result ) ))` which is likely why it complains about the `map` not existing. But even if it were the equivalent (assuming reasonable implementation of `map`) `args.flatMap( (arg:String) => toIntSafe(arg))`, it still shouldn't type-check.

Comment: What you want to do here is, both: iterate over `List` (one monad) and handle errors using `Either` (another monad) - to do both of that in one monad (which would allow doing it in one for comprehension) you would need a monad transformer e.g. `EitherT[List, String, ?]` - that is true in Haskell as well and no implicit magic would align this for you.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok While I agree Monad transformers are the way to go if I wanted to make this bigger, this small enough example works for me in Haskell (see edit). I wonder what it takes to make it work in Scala.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I think I found the problem; I am doing the Monad composition in the return statement in Haskell. If I try to do this inside the do block with assignment statements, this does not typecheck. I bet I can wrap with ErrorM in the `yield` part of my for comprehension in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your haskell code and your scala code are not equivalent:

```
do
  arg <- s
  return . toIntSafe $ arg
```

corresponds to

```
for {
      arg <- args
    } yield toIntSafe(arg)
```

Which compiles fine.

To see why your example one doesn't compile, we can desugar it:

```
for {
      arg <- args
      result <- toIntSafe(arg)
   } yield result

=

args.flatMap { arg =>
  toIntSafe(arg).map {result => result}
}
```

Now looking at types:

```
args: List[String]
args.flatMap: (String => List[B]) => List[B]
arg => toIntSafe(arg).map {result => result} : String => ErrorM[Int]
```

Which shows the problem. `flatMap` is expecting a function returning a `List` but you are giving it a function returning an `ErrorM`.

Haskell code along the lines of:

```
do
    arg <- s
    result <- toIntSafe arg
    return result
```

wouldn't compile either for roughly the same reason: trying to bind across two different monads, List and Either.

A for comprehension in scala will or a do expression in haskell will only ever work for the same underlying monad, because they are both basically syntactic translations to series of `flatMap`s and `>>=`s respectively. And those still need to typecheck.

If you want to compose monads one thing you can do use monad transformers ( EitherT), although in your above example I don't think you want to, since you actually want to sequence in the end.

Finally, in my opinion the most elegant way of expressing your code is:

```
def convert(args: List[String]) = args.traverse(toIntSafe)
```

Because `map` followed by `sequence` is `traverse`

Comment: Check out my last comment on the question

Comment: Any explanation on why the return statement and yield are immune to monadic composition? If yes I'll give you the answer